# Unit test onComplete callback for $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I have an Angular service that contains the following method:

```
function showDialog() {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'SampleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        onComplete: function () {
            service.doSomething();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I test **onComplete** callback of $mdDialog? I have managed to test if $mdDialog.show is called but I cannot get the test callback to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$mdDialog.show()` will not resolve on its own during unit testing. To simulate that behavior, you need to override the show method in your tests and call the onComplete function yourself. A simple example would look something like:

```
$mdDialog.show = function (options) {
  options.onComplete();
};

// Call your function
showDialog();
```

However, that ignores the promise normally returned by `$mdDialog.show()`. A more complete override that supports promise chains, i.e. `$mdDialog.show().then()`, requires returning a dummy promise and resolving it manually as well:

```
// Create a dummy promise we can resolve manually
var deferred = $q.defer(); 

$mdDialog.show = function (options) {
  options.onComplete();

  // Return the dummy promise
  return deferred.promise;
};

// Call your function
showDialog();

// Resolve the promise, which won't actually be resolved until apply is called
deferred.resolve();
$rootScope.$apply();
```